# upgrading to angular application to v10 error getting

Tags: angular, typescript

Am executing demo app .Am new to angulat. and Below is my caltegory list component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AngularGridInstance, Column, GridOption, GraphqlService, GraphqlResult, Filters, Formatters, OnEventArgs, FieldType } from 'angular-slickgrid';

import { CategoryDataService } from 'src/app/core/services/category-data.service';
import { PageService } from 'src/app/core/services/page.service';


const GRAPHQL_QUERY_DATASET_NAME = 'categories';


@Component({
  templateUrl: './category-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-list.component.css']
})
export class CategoryListComponent implements OnInit {
  angularGrid: AngularGridInstance;
  columnDefinitions: Column[];
  gridOptions: GridOption;
  dataset = [];

  constructor(private dataService: CategoryDataService, private router: Router, private pageService: PageService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columnDefinitions = [
        ...removed
    ];

    this.gridOptions = {
      backendServiceApi: {
        service: new GraphqlService(),
        options: {
          columnDefinitions: this.columnDefinitions,
          datasetName: GRAPHQL_QUERY_DATASET_NAME
        },
        process: (query) => this.getCategories(),
      }
    };;
  }

 
  getCategories(): Observable<GraphqlResult> {
    var args = this.pageService.getPageArgs(this.angularGrid);

    return this.dataService.searchCategories(args)
      .pipe(map(
        page => {
          var result: GraphqlResult = {
            data: {
              [GRAPHQL_QUERY_DATASET_NAME]: {
                nodes: page.items,  ---here i am getting error
                pageInfo: {
                  hasNextPage: page.hasNextPage
                },
                totalCount: page.totalCount
              }
            }
          };

          return result;
        }));
  }
}
```

The demo project working fine before. and when i updated to latest slick grid version , i am getting below error.. it is showing not type any ...
Pls let me know how to convert generic class to any type ..Thanks

[image: Error]

And interface for Pagination.

```
export interface IPagedList<T> {
     pageIndex: number;
     .... removed
    
    items: T[];
}
```

Error:
***Type of computed property's value is '{ nodes: IProduct[]; pageInfo: { hasNextPage: boolean; }; totalCount: number; }', which is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'nodes' does not exist in type 'any[]'.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a small breaking change in version `2.15.x` of Angular-Slickgrid, I added a new Type `GraphqlPaginatedResult` when using Pagination and `GraphqlResult` when you're not, it's more representative of which one is which. So you just need to switch your Type to `GraphqlPaginatedResult`. I didn't want to release a breaking version (`3.x`) just for that 1 small Type change (and I thought no one were using the GraphQL portion lol), so you'll need to update your code (just do a find+replace from `GraphqlResult` to `GraphqlPaginatedResult`).

```
getCategories(): Observable<GraphqlPaginatedResult> {
```

It was explained in this [Release](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/releases/tag/v2.15.4) changelog.

Also when that change was done, I created a new [Example 27 - Graphql without Pagination](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/graphql-nopage) which is the one that uses `GraphqlResult` while the previous [Example 6 - Graphql](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/gridgraphql) uses the new `GraphqlPaginatedResult` Type.